# WPF - Get ElementName for the EventTrigger from other DataTemplate in one xaml file

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate, eventtrigger

Good morning,

Could you please give me advice how would be better to resolve the issue with Binding of elements form different DataTemplates.

I have two DataTemplate(s) in one common xaml file.
In one of them I need to add the EventTrigger with appropriate binding to the command in ViewModel.
I very need to pass parameters with ElementName from other DataTemplate as CommandParameter to the ViewModel.
And second binding does not work.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SpecifiedCommand}">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SpecialConverter}">
                   <Binding ElementName="First"/> <!--current Datatemplate-->

                   <Binding ElementName="Second"/> <!--other Datatemplate-->
               </MultiBinding>
           </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
       </i:InvokeCommandAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Could you please, give me advice how would be better to implement this code.